# The Helly Property in the family of closed intervals on the real line

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

I am given the following definition of the Helly Property and asked to apply it to the family of closed intervals on the real line; i.e., show that the Helly Property applies to said family.

> A family of sets has the Helly Property if the members of each pairwise intersecting subfamily have an element in common.

My understanding must be fundamentally flawed because I reason to take a subfamily $\{ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] \}$, whose pairwise intersection is empty, to show that the property does not apply.

Could someone please help clarify the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Helly property says that **if** a subfamily is pairwise intersecting, **then** there's an element contained in every set of the subfamily.

The subfamily $\{[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]\}$ is not pairwise intersecting, so the Helly property does not require anything of it.

Even the subfamily $\{[1,3],[2,5],[4,6]\}$ is not pairwise intersecting, since $[1,3] \cap [4,6]$ is empty.

An example of a pairwise intersecting family is $\{[1,3], [2,4], [3,5]\}$, since all three of the intersections $[1,3] \cap [2,4]$, $[1,3] \cap [3,5]$, and $[2,4] \cap [3,5]$ are nonempty. And in fact there is an element - namely, $3$ - contained in all three intervals, as the Helly property promises.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. +1